# Connection Jenkins socks5 BitBucket

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, socks

This is my 1st question (I read the steps, and hope do it right).

We are working with Jenkins in a inner network. That network has a proxy Socks5 that allows the connection in internet.

In other network we have a BitBucket server that has to be connected by ssh.

We configured Jenkins to use proxy as is sown in the image
[Bitbucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ighkk.png)

The keys (private and public) are generated and are right configured (we checked it by putty and git cli)

When we add the BB repo we found a problem and we cant connect it.
Any idea what is happening??
Thanks!!!
[Jenkins cofig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9W9w.png)

**Update**
I am testing without the proxy configuration and the issue is the same. May be something missing in the proxy configuration??
When I checking the BB repo, its ok 
[Check repo with proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceL8c.png)

But when I tried to add it, the problem persists
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Tzz.png)

Comment: Is there any error message shown?

Comment: Thanks for reply!! No, just the shown in the 2 pic (Jenkins config)